# SOLR Highlighting on Body Text field based on matching a different field which contains an index to match against

Tags: solr, highlight

I have a utility which takes a document and processes it and generates a unique set of tags which are used to index the document sentence by sentence.

I am writing these new tags into a different field than the content field.

I was wondering if there is any way to ask highlighting to perform a match against the special tags but to show the highlight of the original content.

Alternately, I could embed the source sentence in part of my overall index and set some file marker so that if the highlighter matched the section with the index it could return the text in the tag.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a possible use case for [Payloads](https://lucidworks.com/2017/09/14/solr-payloads/) combined with `{!payload_check} `. I don't have any experience with it myself, but that's where I'd start my research.

Comment: Thank MatsLindh yes I've looked at payloads. It's more designed to put numbers in and then be able to perform a query sum based on match (min, max, avg functs). I believe they are per term and also are not open to a HL query. so not exactly a solution.

Comment: There is payload strings, and you can use those payload strings for querying (i.e. for getting matching tokens). These matching tokens should (in theory) be able to go further through highlighting, and thus, highlight those tokens that have matching payloads. This is a theory, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: payload is at token scope. wheres I will work at sentence scope. so its a bit difficult. But I might be able to do something inverted, like create a document of special tokens, and stuff the sentence in as a payload. But I dont think you can highlight the payload value, only match.

Comment: In my suggestion you'd use the same payload value for all tokens in the same sentence, meaning that each word in the sentence would match.